# AWS Cognito SignInWithApple throws apple_sub Attribute does not exist in the schema error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am currently developing SignInWithApple federation using amazon cognito. During the user cognito apple signup I receive a callback with apple_sub Attribute does not exist in the schema error. Full callback url below:

```
https://www.localhost:3000/cognito/oauth/callback?error_description=Invalid+user+attributes%3A+apple_sub%3A+Attribute+does+not+exist+in+the+schema.%0A+&state=provider%3DSignInWithApple&error=invalid_request
```

I have tried connecting my cognito to a PreSignUp_ExternalProvider lambda trigger and deleting the apple sub attribute via the code below:

```
// appleSignIn has an obsolete apple_sub userAttributes
// that is not present inside AWS infrastructure and causes crashes
if (eventData?.request?.userAttributes?.apple_sub) {
    delete eventData.request.userAttributes.apple_sub
}
```

This worked marvelously until today. Today, For some reason, even when I delete the apple_sub user attribute before passing the event further, I am still receiving the error above.

I have also tried adding a custom apple_sub attribute, but that didn't help me also. There is also no apple_sub standard attribute to be found.

Is there a way how to add standardized apple_sub attribute to my cognito schema? Why is it not there by default when I allow SignInWithApple federation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have in the meantime found the answer to my own question, I had a fatal mistake in my cloudformation attribute mapping:

```
AttributeMapping:
    apple_sub: "sub"
    email: "email"
```

- the apple_sub attribute is nonexistent in my schema. At the same time, the AWS console wrongly shows that the sub attribute is mapped to User pool Username attribute, even though it isn't

thus, the correct format of my UserPoolAppleIdentityProvider attribute mapping is:

```
UserPoolAppleIdentityProvider:
    Type: AWS::Cognito::UserPoolIdentityProvider
    Properties:
        AttributeMapping:
        username: "sub"
        email: "email
```

or ideally, delete the username: "sub" from the mapping alltogether, since it's obsolete.